# Textwrangler: How can I Replace \d+ with {\d+}?

Tags: replace, find, textwrangler

I need to find and replace the text [*n*] with the text \textsuperscript{*n*}.

Where *n* is a number between 1-99.

EG. the text [15] with the text \textsuperscript{15}

I am not a programmer but think grep is my friend here.

I have tried:
Find: `\[\d+\]`
Replace: `\\textsuperscript{\d+}`
this finds the numbers but replaces them with \textsuperscript{\d+} (predictably).

Where am I going wrong please?

Thanks for your help.
Found the solution over on Google Groups for Textwrangler. Apparently I needed a subpattern.

Find:   `\[(\d+)\]`

Repalce: `\\textsuperscript\{\1}`

Here is a link to the [Solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/textwrangler/DR7PNz7cJY0)

Comment: I don't know textwrangler, but something like `find: \[(\d+)\]` and `replace: textsuperscript{$1}` should work. Or `\1` instead of `$1`

Comment: Thanks, but sadly it didn't work. Just faithfully replaces with no number, tried a lot of different combinations of your suggestions.

Comment: Strange. According to documentation it accepts PCRE syntax for regex. Did you check `Use Grep`?

Comment: I did use grep for my searches. As this is solved I am wondering how I report this question as solved please?

Comment: Answer the question below and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. Found the solution over on Google Groups for Textwrangler. Apparently I needed a subpattern.

Find:  `\[(\d+)\]`

Repalce: `\\textsuperscript\{\1}`

Here is a link to the [Solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/textwrangler/DR7PNz7cJY0)